# "Had that happened" vs "if that had happened"

Tags: grammar, irrealis-mood

Consider the following two sentences:

1. If that had happened, she would've won.
2. Had that happened, she would've won.

Is there any difference in meaning between them?

Are they both considered grammatical and common in British and American English?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the first sentence!

Comment: I think that they both mean the same thing: if something happens then the result for each is that she would've won. I live in America so I don't know about British english, but both are considered grammatical and are fairly common in American English.

Comment: @JoeKerr Thanks for the feedback! Please consider turning your comment into an answer.